# Angularjs ng-table pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, ngtable

I am new to angular not really got my head round it yet so please if there is any obvious mistakes or a better way to achieve what I'm doing let me know.

Im using a factory to share data between controllers. I'm doing this as there is going to be a lot of requests that list large chunks of data.

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app.customers')
    .controller('CustomersController', CustomersController)
    .factory('dataShare',function($rootScope,$timeout){
        var service = {};
        service.data = false;
        service.sendData = function(data){
            this.data = data;
            $timeout(function(){
                $rootScope.$broadcast('data_shared');
            },100);
        };
        service.getData = function(){
            return this.data;
        };
        return service;
    });
```

And in a controller I am doing

```
$http.post("http://api.dev/v1/customers/search", $scope.searchData)
     .then(function (response) {
           $scope.customers = response.data;
           dataShare.sendData(response.data);
       }, 
//....
```

I have a separate controller for NgTables where I have this:

```
$scope.$on('data_shared',function(){
        $scope.customers = [{}];
        var data =  dataShare.getData();
        console.log("here");
        $scope.customers = data;

      console.log($scope.customers.length);
      vm.tableParams3 = new ngTableParams({
          page: 1,            // show first page
          count: 10,
          // count per page
      }, {
          total: $scope.customers.length, // length of data
          getData: function (params) {
              // use build-in angular filter
              var filteredData = params.filter() ?
                      $filter('filter')($scope.customers, params.filter()) :
                      $scope.customers;
              var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                      $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                      $scope.customers;

              params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination
              return (orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
          }
      });
```

The data is being passed correctly and output of console.log is what is expected however the page count is just being completely ignored. But if I change the page option below it will start from that page.

```
 vm.tableParams3 = new ngTableParams({
          page: 1,            // show first page
          count: 10,          // count per page
      },
```

I have tried all sorts, read about 20 different questions and the ng-tables docs but no matter what i do I cant get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm by no means an expert in Angular, but to me, it appears to be simply setting the page number.

Under your

```
$scope.customers = data;
```

try setting the page you wish to start at.

```
$scope.page = "1";
```